# How can I calculate the size of files which will push after commit?

Tags: git, git-push

How can I calulate the size of repository that need to commit?

How can I calculate the size of files which will push after commit?

Answer (score 5):

`git count-objects -vH` should contains all your needs. `in-pack` is the size of the next pending commit.